# Difference between "I took a long time" and "I was a long time."

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I have read a children's book for language learners. It's a book from the Oxford Reading Tree series. There is a character who goes to the dentist, and when she comes back home she says:

> "Sorry I was a long time."

I want to ask what's the difference between:

> I took a long time

and

> I was a long time.

Is there any difference in meaning? Is this phrase

> "I was a long time"

more native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *outcome* of the two statements means the same thing (a long time passed) but there is a different inference.

> I was a long time.

There could be so many different reasons *why* you were a long time. Maybe you got delayed by something or someone, or maybe you created the delay yourself.

> I *took* a long time.

"Take" is a *verb* and the action is your own. If you *took* a long time it implies that you deliberately took your time, perhaps lingering, taking a detour, or just acting slowly.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are not lucky with any of those sentences. None of them really makes sense in English. I assume that the first sentence was (supposed to be) actually:

> <strike>Sorry, it was a long time.</strike>

But even then, it is not OK (the reason for striking it). It is going to be good if you say:

> (Sorry,) **it** took a long time.

---

A correct alternative to the first sentence would be:

> Sorry, I was gone for a long time.